# Angular Provider with data from websocket

Tags: angularjs, websocket

I want to create a provider (or other service) in AngularJS that return data from subscribe websocket. How can I get data from my provider to scopes in real-time?

Sample:

```
app.provider('MyProvider', function () {

    this.$get = function () {

        var dataFromProvider ;

        ws.subscribe('subscribeTopic', function (data) { 

            var dataFromProvider = data;             

        });

        return {
            dataFromProvider: dataFromProvider
        }       

    }

});
```

---

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, MyProvider) {

$scope.myData = MyProvider.dataFromProvider;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a service with [RxJS Extensions for Angular](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js).

```
app.provider('MyProvider', function () {

    this.$get = function (rx) {
        var subject = new rx.Subject();
        ws.subscribe('subscribeTopic', function (data) { 
             subject.onNext(data);             
        });

        return { subject: subject }; 

    }

});
```

### Usage

```
app.controller("myVm", function($scope, MyProvider) {
    var subscription = MyProvider.subject.subscribe(function(data) {
         $scope.data = data;
    });
    $scope.$on("$destroy", subscription.dispose);
});
```

An rxSubject can handle multiple subscribers and works with all the standard rxJS filters and combinators.

For example of a service using [angular.rx.js](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js), see [this DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y2hQkAC74JeY9WO1OxpV?p=preview)